# VSCode FileSystemProvider API: is there any way to use built-in hot shutdown backup capabilities?

Tags: visual-studio-code, vscode-extensions

I am developing a VSCode extension which tries to make the most of the VSCode's editing capabilities, specifically backing up dirty states of the editor tabs if VSCode is shut down improperly.

The extension implements a custom `FileSystemProvider` to represent the remote resources, but the file content itself is pure text, no binaries. And I have noticed that VSCode does not want to backup those documents and on each reload the unsaved changes are lost.

I assume that this functionality is blocked for the custom registered schemas. Is it correct? Is there any way to use those capabilities or by implementing additional APIs?

Comment: why do you close the editor with unsaved changes, get in the habit of saving

Comment: The scenario here is to preserve the changes of edited files in a case of VSCode emergency shutdown, this is what that backup feature is for. In a case of a normal exit, VSC obviously offers you to save/do not save edited files before quitting.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems like backup functionality is disabled while debugging in Extension Host. When an extension with registered custom `FileSystemProvider` is running in the usual VSCode instance, the content of opened editors are backed up as expected.